# Why can't I get pgrep output right to variable on bash script?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, exit-status, pgrep

I'm trying to make a script to either quit compton if it's running or start it if it's not running. I've read from man that it should exit 1 if process is found, so I've tried to make a script that uses that... However this just doesn't work, It starts if it's closed but doesn't close it. what am I doing wrong ??

```
#!/bin/bash


status=$(pgrep compton 2>&1)

if [[ $status == 1 ]];
    then
        killall compton
    else
        exec compton -b
fi

echo $status
```

Comment: `0` or `1` is **exit status**,  but `$(...)` captures **output**.

Comment: grab `$?` . do `man bash`.

Answer (score 8):

You *are* getting the `pgrep` output in your `status` variable.  It's just not the output that you expect it to be.

`pgrep` outputs the process IDs (PIDs) of the processes matching the pattern that you give it.  If there is a process whose name matches `compton`, then `$status` would be the PID of that process, or of those processes.  `pgrep` also returns an exit status, but an exit status is not captured by a command substitution as a string.

In your test, you compare `$status` against `1`.  It is unlikely that `compton` has PID 1.

---

If you want to kill any `compton` process if they exist, and start `compton -b` if no `compton` process exists, you may do that with

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! pkill compton; then
    exec compton -b
fi
```

This uses the exit status of `pkill`.  The `pkill` tool works in an equivalent way to `pgrep` (they are usually distributed and installed as a pair) but instead of outputting PIDs of matching processes like `pgrep` would do, `pkill` sends the `TERM` signal (by default) to the matching processes.

The `if` keyword uses the exit status of the command that you use with it.

The `!` inverts the sense of the test so that

- If `pkill compton` succeeds, it means that there *was* one or several `compton` processes that have now been killed, or at least signalled, and `exec compton -b` will not be executed.
- If `pkill compton` fails (no process matched the name, or there was some internal error in `pkill`), the body of the `if` statement would call your `exec compton -b`, which would replace the shell process with the process resulting from running `compton -b`.

Answer (score 6):

You should control exit status of pgrep process which will be in $? variable. Or check if $status variable where you're storing the output of pgrep is f.e. non zero-length string. The script in the question checks whether string in variable status is "1"

so

```
#!/bin/bash
pgrep compton >/dev/null

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    killall compton
else
    exec compton -b
fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
status=$(pgrep compton 2>&1)

if [[ -n "$status" ]]
then
    killall compton
else
    exec compton -b
fi
```

Comment: `if pgrep compton >/dev/null; then` is the better practice, so one doesn't directly inspect `$?` at all. In addition to avoiding bugs where `$?` refers to a different command than you think it does when editing code to add logging or such, this also means that `set -e` will no longer treat `pgrep` returning 1 as cause to exit the script (because branching on its exit status marks it as "checked").

Comment: @charles Duffy. Pardon me if this is an ignorant question, but how would one store the exit status according to your suggestion?

Comment: @adamlogan that's the point. You don't need to store exit status in variable and compare variable in condition. You can use command as a condition which works the same way.
`if command; then … ;fi` or `if ! command; then … ; fi`